# How do i enable "cognito user pool" option in app client settings through terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito

I am able to specify "Facebook" in the "supported_identity_providers" argument and it works. I tried specifying the name, id and the word "Cognito User Pool" for the supported identity providers argument and it keeps throwing validation error.

[image]

I want the option pointed by the arrow enabled from terraform. What value do I pass to the  "supported_identity_providers" argument?

Comment: A trick you can use is to check that box then run `terraform plan` and it will refresh the current state and it will tell you what it needs to change about the resource to comply to your code. You can then see which property of that resource changes when you check the box and update your code accordingly.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Worked! Thank you. Brilliant idea

Comment: It also works if you can import a resource, for something you haven't set up in Terraform before. I use it alot!

Answer (score 41):

**Short answer**

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "<name>" {
  ...
  supported_identity_providers = ["COGNITO", ...]
  ...
}
```

**Details**

The AWS API for creating a user pool client can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPoolClient.html) and the terraform docs [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cognito_user_pool_client.html).

Both are missing the default names for the standard providers (Cognito, Amazon, Google, Facebook).

I wasn't been able to find any amazon documentation on the default names of the user pool client's `SupportedIdentityProviders` value, only a pattern in the AWS API docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_UserPoolClientType.html#CognitoUserPools-Type-UserPoolClientType-SupportedIdentityProviders).

When writing the terraform code I had to toggle on the values in the AWS console, then use the CLI to retrieve the values:

`aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool-client --user-pool-id <pool-id> --client-id <client-id>`

For cognito this gives back `COGNITO` the social providers are `Google`, `Facebook`, and `LoginWithAmazon`. If you are using OIDC/SAML it is the `provider name` you have configured.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also wouldn't hurt to add a documentation link to where this is explained. Also I think it should be a `}` at the end.